# build dynamic field in form symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm asking you for a little advice on creating a specific form in Symfony3.

I need to create a form that upload's an unspecified number of files, which every file has a description text input that belongs to that file.

Answer (score 1):

That's the doc you're looking for https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Come back for more details later :)